# Composer Autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-0

I'm currently trying to use PSR-0 autoloading with Composer, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Twitter\Twitter' not found
```

My directory structure looks like this

```
- Project
    - src
        - Twitter
            Twitter.php
    - vendor
    - Test
    index.php
```

My index.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

    use Twitter;
    $twitter = new Twitter();
```

My Twitter.php file looks like this

```
<?php 

namespace Twitter;

class Twitter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Code Here
    }
}
```

And finally my composer.json looks like this:

```
{
"require": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.8.*@dev",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "3.7.*@dev"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Twitter" : "src/Twitter"
    }
}
}
```

I am getting a little confused. I come from a C# background and this way of working is kinda confusing me. What's the correct way to use PSR-0 autoloading?

Comment: You will also have to include the autoloader.php file - but then, if everything else is defined in the composer.json file, that may well be the only thing you explicitly load with a require/include. Se the Composer FAQs for more details how to use it.

Answer (score 11):

In your composer.json use:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
}
```

or

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Twitter\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

and then run `php composer.phar dump-autoload`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
"psr-0": {
     "Twitter" : "src/"
 }
```

This instructs composer to create autoloader, that will look in `src` for everything from `Twitter` namespace. And since it is `PSR-0`, namespace is treated as a folder and added to declared path, so you should not include it in path part in `composer.json`

Comment: "so you should not include it composer.json" what do you mean by this?

Comment: Missed few words, you should not include it in path part

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Is there any information online that explains how to do this? Are the rest of my files set up correctly?

Comment: I forgot to add ... require 'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: As for documentation, sure there is - http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

> My index.php file looks like this:
>
> ```
> use Twitter;
> $twitter = new Twitter();
> ```

If it's your index.php you forgot to include the composer's autoload script first.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading for details.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your index.php, should be:

`use Twitter\Twitter;
$twitter = new Twitter();`

or

`$twitter = new Twitter\Twitter();`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late reply but the first thing you need to make "autoloading" works is have your PHP version be 5.6 and above.