# How to load Pheanstalk in PHP?

Tags: php, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I'm trying to get Pheanstalk working for PHP but I can't load it.

I downloaded the source code from `https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk`, I moved src/Pheanstalk to my project directory, and then did the following in `test.php`:

```
use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;
$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk' not found in test.php on line 2
```

How do I just use Pheanstalk from the cloned git repository?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181181/composer-autoloading

Comment: @Quantastical Thanks, looking into it. I dont know what composer is though...

Comment: Me either, but upon looking at pheanstalk's github, it states `// Hopefully you're using Composer autoloading.` I presume it is some way of autoloading class files based on JSON descriptions of where the source lives, but you could just as easily do an `include( ... );` to the `src/Pheanstalk` code.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a article on Beanstalk, Beanstalkd and Pheanstalk;

Check it out: [How to install Beanstalkd and Pheanstalk on Ubuntu](http://www.william.ro/how-to-install-beanstalkd-and-pheanstalk-on-ubuntu/2014/10/03/)

The solution for your problem is there.

1). Install `Ubuntu Desktop` or `Server` using a `Virtual Machine`.

I used `Oracle VM VirtualBox` for this example.

Make sure that a `Bridged Network Connection` has been set.

Set a username and a password when asked to.

I used:

username: `william`
password: `123456`

2). Start Ubuntu and Login

3). Login as Super User

use: `sudo su`
and enter the super user password when requested ( mine is: 123456 );

4). Install `Open SSH` and access the `Ubuntu virtual machine` via `Putty`.

docs: `https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html`

use: `apt-get install openssh-client`

to install the client and then

use: `apt-get install openssh-server`

to install the server;

5). Install `Apache2` web server

use: `apt-get install apache2`

now type the following in a browser:

`http://localhost`

and
your virtual machine ip ( mine was `192.168.1.104` )

6). Install `MySQL`

use: `apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql`

set password for `MySQL root` user: 123456
repeat password: 123456

7). Install `PHP5`

use: `apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt`

8). Install `cURL`

use: `apt-get install curl`

9). Install `Composer`

official website: `https://getcomposer.org/`
docs: `https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md` ( Getting Started )

use: `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
or
use: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
now, composer.phar must be moved and converted

use: `mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer`

10). Install `Beanstalkd`

use: `apt-get install beanstalkd`

now, let's make sure that `beanstalkd persistent mode is active`

ps ax

ps ax | grep beans

locate beanstalkd.conf

updatedb

locate beanstalkd.conf

`nano /etc/default/beanstalk`

`uncomment last line in order to save persistent mode to active`

11). Install `Pheanstalk`

docs: `https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk`

change directory
use: `cd /var/www/html`

create a new directory: /var/www/html/pheanstalk_test
use: `mkdir pheanstalk_test`

change directory to the new created directory
use: `cd pheanstalk_test`

create a composer.json file under this new directory
use: `nano composer.json`

write the following data in the file:
`{
"require":{
"pda/pheanstalk":"v3.0.0"
}
}`

and save the file ( push Ctrl+X keys, push Y key, push ENTER key )

use: `composer update`

now, the vendor folder data should begin to download

or use: `git clone https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk.git`

examples:
how to put data on tube/s

`<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;
$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');
while(true){
$tube_id=rand(1,9);
$r1=rand(1,10000000);
$r2=rand(1,10000000);
$pheanstalk->useTube('testtube'.$tube_id)->put('{'.$r1.':'.$r2.'}');
}
?>`

use: php put.php
and a put process will start
info! the more instances open, the more data gets put on the tube/s

how to get data from tube/s

`<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;
$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');
while(true){
$tube_id=rand(1,9);
$job=$pheanstalk->watch('testtube'.$tube_id)->ignore('default')->reserve();
if($job){
echo $job->getdata();
$pheanstalk->delete($job);
}
}
?>`

use: php get.php
and a get process will start
info! the more instances open, the more data gets processed;

12). Install `Beanstalk Console`

docs: `https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console`

change directory

use: `cd /var/www/html`

create a new folder

use: `mkdir beanstalk_console`

use: `git clone https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console.git`

change the rights for the file: storage.json
`chmod 777 storage.json`

now, to access `beanstalk console`, write in the browser: `http://localhost/beanstalk_console/public`

13). This is it!

Comment: Thanks. I'm not seeing `vendor/autoload.php` though. Where should this folder be?

Comment: step 11: Install Pheanstalk

Comment: after step 11, the vendor folder and a composer.lock file should be there

Comment: Could you share vendor/autoload.php please? In a gist or pastebin? I don't see it anywhere after step 11... Are you installing the latest Pheanstalk? It appears it has been removed...

Comment: i will paste it later today, the file is not available to me now

Comment: Hey Ionus nice answer, vero complete. I am starting to use pheanstalk and have a few doubts myself. I created a question, might you be able to give me your insight on it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370688/pheanstalk-and-beanstalk-functions

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by Ionut is viable for getting Pheanstalk working, it doesn't actually answer the question posed: How do you get Pheanstalk working from a git clone of the project repo? (Implicit here is that you don't want to use Composer for the installation, which is the assumption I'll be using for this answer.)

The main issue is that you can't just `require('src/Pheanstalk.php');` and then start using the Pheanstalk class. The Pheanstalk library relies heavily on PHP class autoloading, so without that setup, it will error out as described in the original question.

If you have a PSR-4 compliant autoloader for your project already, great! Point it at the psr-4 section of the composer.json file and watch the magic work.

For everyone else, however, you'll want to use the function provided by  Thibault in his answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39774973

Assuming you have the Pheanstalk git repo cloned into your project at `pheanstalk`, you can then just use `loadPackage('pheanstalk')` and it should all work properly.

Full example:

```
function loadPackage($dir)
{
    $composer = json_decode(file_get_contents("$dir/composer.json"), 1);
    $namespaces = $composer['autoload']['psr-4'];

    // Foreach namespace specified in the composer, load the given classes
    foreach ($namespaces as $namespace => $classpath) {
        spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) use ($namespace, $classpath, $dir) {
            // Check if the namespace matches the class we are looking for
            if (preg_match("#^".preg_quote($namespace)."#", $classname)) {
                // Remove the namespace from the file path since it's psr4
                $classname = str_replace($namespace, "", $classname);
                $filename = preg_replace("#\\\\#", "/", $classname).".php";
                include_once $dir."/".$classpath."/$filename";
            }
        });
    }
} 

loadPackage(__DIR__."/pheanstalk");

use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;

$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');

echo $pheanstalk->getConnection()->isServiceListening();
```